# Exponential/recursive smoothing

Tags: matlab, smoothing, exponential

I need to estimate power of signal over time using exponential or recursive smoothing. I got this formula

```
Px[n] = αPx[n-1] + (1-α)x[n]^2
```

and the signal is

```
Fs = 8000;                 
dt = 1/Fs;                   
StopTime = 5;          
t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)';
L=length(t);
noise=1*randn(L,1);
```

for alpha=0.999 power signal should look like this
https://puu.sh/C8w2h/df180c8491.png
How can I do it?

Comment: any reason while a simple for-loop would not be acceptable?

Comment: Everything is acceptable

Comment: then use that! This looks like a work assignment and `for` is, like, programming level 0. You should really have a look at the documentation and learn how to do it in Matlab.